# Is it theoretically possible to avoid G force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration

Eventually, you could need to get out of somewhere or get to somewhere very fast. You wouldn't have time to accelerate slowly. Unfortunately, very high accelerations are bad to living things. We can die crushed just because of a gigantic G force.

Is that a problem we will have forever?

Comment: Probably important to read what [g-force is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force) in the first place, then think about if it's possible to remove it.

Comment: note that of the 5 rather reputable members of the site who closed your question, I was not one of them. Criticizing them (and me) is no way to get your question reopened.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2476/25301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but none of them are feasible until now.

You have to compensate the gravitational (or intertial) acceleration in the whole body, equally.

1. Electromagnetic interaction. Diamagnetic levitation were already used to levitate frogs. Diamagnetism essentially means, that everything, including a living frog, has a - very small - repulsive magnetic force in the presence of strong magnetic field.

[image]

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1vyB-O5i6E).

Superconducting magnets are needed to levitate a single frog. It is currently impossible to do the same with humans. This could compensate 1G.

2. Gravitational interaction.

Theory currently suggests that roughly at $10^{19} GeV$ energy the unification of the gravitational interaction and the others [could be possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything). On the General Relativity, the acceleration due to inertia ("G-force") and the acceleration due to gravity are the same. Thus, an experimentally usable TOE could do this. Considering that the current accelerator energy is roughly $7000 GeV$, it seems more like fantasy now.

Comment: I see what you mean about levitation : if force is applied equally at all points in the body, it will not be crushed when it is accelerated. ... But I do not understand your 2nd point.

Comment: @sammygerbil I tried to explain a possible, very far future in which a TOE could be applied into the engineering practice (i.e. anti-gravitation). I am open to any idea, how could I make this part better.