# What if gravitational mass and inertial mass of a body had different values?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, mass

From the equivalence principle we know that the gravitational and inertial mass of a body have same values.  But I'm just wondering what would the universe be like if they had different values?

Comment: This question got downvoted within 10 minutes. It doesn't deserve it. It is not "If the universe was different, what would it be like?" That doesn't have a good answer. This is specific. People have done experiments to see if the two masses are the same. What would we expect to see if they were different?

Comment: You can find more here. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9321/37364

Comment: @mmesser314 To be fair, it's not clear to me that he is saying "different from each other" or just "different" in general.  The question isn't really clear enough IMO.

Comment: I mean their values were different.

Comment: @JMac Within the context of the question, it is very clear that OP is asking how the universe would be different if the gravitational and inertial mass of a single body were different **from each other**. This is a well-posed question and I see no reason to state it as unclear or close it.

Comment: @BobKnighton Read the edit history, question wasn't clear originally.

Comment: @JMac My bad. Good edits.

Comment: Which mass is larger, by how much? Or maybe those aspects are irrelevant. Would  stars even form or be long-lived since accelerations would be mass number dependent and hydrogen would gather at a different rate than helium and lithium?

Comment: Interesting question. Bummer that it got closed. Perhaps the theorized universe would then be more like we see it. [Allegedly](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/7x3ed9/darpa-is-researching-quantized-inertia-a-theory-of-physics-many-think-is-pseudoscience) DARPA funded University of Plymouth physicist Mike McCulloch proposed this scenario as an alternative to dark matter for reconciling differences between the equivalence principle and cosmological observations.