# Why are gravitational mass equal to the mass in Newton's second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass

Newtons second involves the mass $m$ e.g.
$$
F = m a
$$

And the gravitation force also involves the mass e.g.
$$
  F = - G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}
$$

The question is why the gravitation mass is equal to the mass in Newton's second law.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a fundamental reason why gravitational mass is the same as inertial mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9321/)

Comment: If that one doesn't do it, there are other ones like it on this site. If still none of them answer the questions you have, you can post your question making sure to reference the possible duplicates and explaining why they are not sufficient